# Understanding the recursion in mergesort-like algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I was wondering how the flow of this recursive algorithm works: [an inversion counter based on merge-sort](http://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~piak/teaching/algo/algo2008/count-inv.htm). When I looked at the diagrams of the merge-sort recursion tree, it seemed fairly lucid; I thought that the leaves would keep splitting until each leaf was a single unit, then `merge()` would start combining them; and therefore, start 'moving back up' the tree -- so to speak.

But in the code below, if we print out this function with a given array `print(sortAndCount(test_case))` then we're actually getting our 'final' output from the `merge()` function, not the return statement in `sortAndCount()`?  So in the code below, I thought that the `sortAndCount()` method  would call itself over and over in `(invCountA, A) = sortAndCount(anArray[:halfN])` until reaching the base case and then moving on to processing the next half of the array -- but now that seems incorrect. Can someone correct my understanding of this recursive flow? (N.b. I truncated some of the code for the `merge()` method since I'm only interested  the recursive process.)

```py
def sortAndCount(anArray):
    N = len(anArray)
    halfN = N // 2

    #base case:
    if N == 1: return (0, anArray)          

    (invCountA, A) = sortAndCount(anArray[:halfN])
    (invCountB, B) = sortAndCount(anArray[halfN:])
    (invCountCross, anArray) = merge(A, B)

    return (invCountA + invCountB + invCountCross, anArray)

def merge(listA, listB):
    counter = 0
    i, j = 0, 0

    #some additional code...
    #...
    #...


    #If all items in one array have been selected, 
    #we just return remaining values from other array:
    if (i == Asize):                                
        return (counter, output_array + listB[j:])
    else:
        return (counter, output_array + listA[i:])
```

Comment: The logic is the same as mergesort the only difference is we count split inversions by counting the items remaining  in the left side when we find an element smaller in the right.

Comment: are you asking about split inversions or mergesort?

Comment: Well, I'm asking about this [split-inversions], but like you said, it's very similar to mergesort. My issue is that I'm trying to unroll the recursive calls. The crux is I'm not sure what happens on the line `(invCountA, A) = sortAndCount(anArray[:halfN])`. Does the interpreter stop to compute every level of the recursion before moving on – i.e. does it finish recursing over `(invCountA, A) = sortAndCount(anArray[:halfN])` until it gets to N size 1, or does it create a placeholder whilst proceeding through the code (and only then going through each level of the recursion)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following image created using [rcviz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcZaD.png) shows the order of recursive call, as explained in the documentation *the edges are numbered by the order in which they were traversed by the execution.The edges are colored from black to grey to indicate order of traversal : black edges first, grey edges last.*:

[image]

So if we follow the steps closely we see that first we traverse the left half of the original array completely then the right.